# Gaussian integers modulo n. Multiplication table for $\mathbb Z_3[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

### Multiplication Table

\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
\hline 
X & 1 & 2 & i & 1+i & 2+i & 2i & 1+2i & 2+2i \\ 
\hline 
1 & 1 & 2 & i & 1+i & 2+i & 2i & 1+2i & 2+2i \\  
2 & 2 & 1 & 2i & 2+2i & 1+2i & i & 2+i & 1+i \\ 
i & i & 2i & 2 & 2+i & 2+2i & 1 & 1+i & 1+2i \\  
1+i & 1+i & 2+2i & 2+i & 2i & 1 & 1+2i & 2 & i \\  
2+i & 2+i & 1+2i & 2+2i & 1 & i & 1+i & 2i & 2 \\  
2i & 2i & i & 1 & 1+2i & 1+i & 2 & 2+2i & 2+i \\  
1+2i & 1+2i & 2+i & 1+i & 2 & 2i & 2+2i & i & 1 \\  
2+2i & 2+2i & 1+i & 1+2i & i & 2 & 2+i & 1 & 2i \\  
\end{array}

First I want to thank you guys for your time. I don't really understand how Gaussian integers modulo n are obtained. This table was given in the Contemporary Abstract Algebra textbook.

First, why is their no row and column for the number 0. Second, How are those entries computed? for example,

$(2+i)(2+i)$ mod $3$ = $4+2i+i^2$ mod $3$  = $(4-1) + i + i$ mod $3$ = $3 - 2$ mod 3 = 1 which is clearly wrong.

If someone can explain this to me I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Some details that might be helpful from the text on this.

Comment: Elements are added and multiplied as in the complex numbers,except the coefficients are reduced modulo 3. In particular, -1 = 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no row or column for $0$ because multiplication by $0$ is just too easy!! - anything times $0$ equals $0$.  You could certainly put in this row and column if you wanted.

You have made a basic mistake in algebra in your second calculation:
$$
(2+i)(2+i)=4+4i+i^2\quad\hbox{not}\quad 4 +2i +i^2\ .$$
Follow this through and you will get the answer $i$ as given.

Comment: Hey thanks man. That was a silly mistake I did their. Okay if we go from their we get 3+4i mod 3. so 3 mod 3 is 0 and 4 mod 3 is 1. Then 3 + 4i mod 3 = 0 + i = i ?

Comment: You got it :)$\!$

Comment: Thanks man, its easier then what it looks like. Really appreciate it